# Sum of a series of exponentiated numbers in `numpy` error

Tags: python, numpy, math, sum, series

In the following code, I test the feasibility of exponentiating series of numbers with the `numpy.prod` and `numpy.sum` math operators.

```
import numpy as np
np.prod((1,2))**5 #(1*2)**5
np.sum((1,2)**5) #(1**5 + 2**5)
```

The first operation works fine, but not the second:

- `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: Well, you can't use powers on a `tuple`.

Comment: First operation converts the tuple into a numpy array and then applies a power. Second operation simply tried to apply a power to a tuple. You will have to convert it to a numpy array first. `np.power` will automatically do that for you. Else, you can use `np.array` explicitly for datatype conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.prod((1,2))**5) #(1*2)**5
print(np.sum(np.power((1,2),5))) #(1**5 + 2**5)
```